# Return column name when the min value matches

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that looks like this -

```
ZIP DC1 DC2 DC3 Min Min(DC)
1   2   3   4   2   DC1
2   5   4   3   3   DC3
```

Basically, I want to populate the last column `Min(DC)`. That column should show respective DC of the `Min` column.  I have been doing it with excel y using vlookp but since my data set has grown, I need to get this done in Teradata or any other sql based format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*, least(dc1, dc2, dc3) as "Min",
       (case least(dc1, dc2, dc3)
            when dc1 then 'dc1'
            when dc2 then 'dc2'
            when dc3 then 'dc3'
        end) as MinCol
```

If you want to return all columns with the minimum value:

```
select t.*, least(dc1, dc2, dc3) as "Min",
       ((case dc1 = least(dc1, dc2, dc3) then 'dc1;' else '' end) ||
        (case dc2 = least(dc1, dc2, dc3) then 'dc2;' else '' end) ||
        (case dc3 = least(dc1, dc2, dc3) then 'dc3;' else '' end) ||
       ) as MinCols
. . .
```

Comment: If `dc1` and `dc3` have the same min value, how can I return `'dc1 & dc3'`? I tried `when (dc1 and dc3) then 'dc1_dc3'` but failed because of syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, in Teradata, you can reference aliased columns in the same query.  I've noticed you can't do that as easily in Postgres, which has become a pain in the butt.  Re-writing the previous query:

```
SELECT t.*, 
LEAST(dc1, dc2, dc3) AS MyMin,
((CASE dc1 = MyMin THEN 'dc1;' ELSE '' END) ||
(CASE dc2 = MyMin THEN 'dc2;' ELSE '' END) ||
(CASE dc3 = MyMin THEN 'dc3;' ELSE '' END) ||
) AS MinCols
```

I haven't checked if this works, but you get the idea.

As for dealing with the case of dc1 = dc3, you can do something like:

```
CASE WHEN dc1 = dc3 THEN dc1 || '_' || dc3 ELSE <blah> END AS <MyExpressionAlias>
```

|| is the concatenate character in SQL

But it looks like the code the previous guy provided will already return what you want if multiple columns share the MinValue.

Comment: Thanks, this worked - `select t.*, least(dc1, dc2, dc3) as Min_TNT,
       ((case when dc1 = Min_TNT then 'dc1;' else '' end) ||
        (case when dc2 =Min_TNT then 'dc2;' else '' end) ||
        (case when dc3 = Min_TNT then 'dc3;' else '' end) 
       ) as MinCols`

Comment: No prob bob :) .